# How get Join.me in Ubuntu?

Tags: wine, proprietary, software-installation

I'd like to know if there's any way of getting join.me to work in Ubuntu? I'm not looking for a similar software. I need it to be join.me.

Comment: Have you tried searching wine hq? http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=27556

Comment: Good catch, I'll give it a try and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using mate and when executing the app the desktop goes black, though I see the join.me top panel. I'll give it a try later with Unity. Thanks!

Comment: I got this http://danielj.se/2012/09/09/how-to-live-stream-your-ubuntu-desktop/ working ... temporarily and very laggy, mind.

Answer (score 10):

There may not be much hope with Join.me of a good cross-platform presentation solution.

For over a year Linux support has been the second-most-popular request on the **official [join.me Ideas Forum](http://help.join.me/forums/182750-join-me-ideas-forum)** and there are over 1800 votes for the idea:

- ***[Make a version compatible with Linux/Ubuntu 12.04 – join.me forum and faq](http://help.join.me/forums/182750-join-me-ideas-forum/suggestions/3466551-make-a-version-compatible-with-linux-ubuntu-12-04)***.

But join.me does not seem to even be willing to comment on the thread.

**Alternatives**

But there are many alternatives. According to comments there, WebEx, Mikogo and Yuuguu support presenting from Linux, and others mentioned are Tightvnc, BigBlueButton and TeamViewer.

**Update**: And of course now add to the list: Jitsi Meet, Zoom, Hangouts Meet, Skype, and many others which use standardized web technologies and are highly cross-platform.

Comment: Uh, join me sucks. it's 2018 and still no linux.

Comment: Make that 2020... Try to download on Linux, it gives you a .exe file.

Comment: any alternatives?

Comment: See my update, @NicolasMolano